# Learner Question: A way to conditionally style a set of fields based on state

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I have a set of fields using MS `Fabric` `UI` which I would like to blur if a `radioButton` is either selected or not.

The fields are all within the one component.

Here's the code:

```
<div className={this.state.BlurOrNot === null ? stylesEvalReq.blurText : stylesEvalReq.noBlurText}>
     <br />
       <div>
       <Label className={stylesEvalReq.questionTitle1}>Job Code and Position Details</Label>
       </div> ETC..
```

I have this function which is triggered when the radio button is selected and changed:

```
private _evalTypeChange = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, option: any) => {
    this.setState({
      EvalType: option.text
    });
    if(option.text === 'New'){
      this.setState({IsEvalTypeDisabled: false});
    } else if(option.text === 'Re-evaluation') {
      this.setState({IsEvalTypeDisabled: true});
    } else if(option.text === 'Appeal') {
      this.setState({IsEvalTypeDisabled: true});
    }

      if(this.state.EvalType === null) {
       this.setState({
        BlurOrNot: true
       }, () => {console.log(this.state.BlurOrNot+'BlurOrNot if null');});
       return <div className={stylesEvalReq.blurText} />;
      } else if (this.state.EvalType === 'New') {
        this.setState({
        BlurOrNot: false
        },() => {console.log(this.state.BlurOrNot+'BlurOrNot if New'+this.state.EvalType+'evaltype');});
      } else if (this.state.EvalType === 'Re-evaluation') {
        this.setState({
        BlurOrNot: false
        }, () => {console.log(this.state.BlurOrNot+'BlurOrNot if Re-evaluation'+this.state.EvalType+'evaltype');});
      } else if (this.state.EvalType === 'Appeal') {
        this.setState({
        BlurOrNot: false
        }, () => {console.log(this.state.BlurOrNot+'BlurOrNot if Appeal'+this.state.EvalType+'evaltype');});
    } 
  }
```

But it's not working because the blurred fields are showing correctly when the radio button is blank but when the New radio button is selected the fields disappear completely. I believe it might be the setState using the previous selected?

Can someone show me where I am going wrong?

EDIT AFTER SOLVED: The BlurOrNot is a Boolean set to null. This is IMPORTANT! :) and also Saqib's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example if the BlurOrnot is true a class that will be applied is `stylesEvalReq.blurText` otherwise `stylesEvalReq.NotblurText` class will be applied.

This ternary operator is the way to make conditional styles.

`className={this.state.BlurOrNot?stylesEvalReq.blurText:stylesEvalReq.NotblurText}`

Comment: Thanks Saqib. I had no idea you could do that in JSX. I've updated my code above to show how I did this for anyone interested.